# Where can I find PCB templates for add on boards

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I want to design some add on boards that will use Mikroe Click Board (TM), Pmod interface and Arduino Interface. The work shall be done in Altium Designer.

Do there exist any PCB templates that I can use as starting point with the connector and silk screen already in place?

Comment: Why not just make your own? I'm sure the specifications exist.

Comment: I could make my own but with a template that already has the correct dimenions, I don't need to worry about that part, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

When I was designing something similar for MSP430 development boards, I just used a vernier caliper to take measurements, noted them on a piece of paper, then designed my own board.

I'd recommend doing that, as this way, you get more flexibility over how you want your board to look. Just make sure you are careful with the measurements.

Here is an example of the most recent one. I've done a couple now for different boards and as long as you take care, measure 4 or 5 times, then you should be fine. I've never had an issue

[image] Here is it attached to the development board

[image] Here it is in full, customised to my own needs and shape

Comment: It's always better to find the original specifications and just double check them with a caliper, especially for mating connector positions.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany if you are careful, it doesn't matter too much. I tend to measure 4 or 5 times before committing, then when it comes to soldering the header pins for mating, I fit them to the target board, get them in the holes on my PCB, then solder them and they stay in place for good mating

Comment: I agree with @SpehroPefhany , Specifications include tolerances,  it's important to recognize that tolerances are not normally distributed, you can have  multiple batches of a component or assembly that are on one extreme. If you develop your layout based on a sample you may be developing a footprint that is biased or over constrained . This has been known to result in unpleasant and expensive situations , binning components, rework and respin of PCBs.

Comment: @crasic for something like interfacing with a development board or Arduino, that isn't likely to be used in a real life product, then my method is perfectly valid. I very much doubt these are going to be mass produced, so tolerances shouldn't be a big deal. If the question was "I want to design a PCB that is going to interface with "x" in a product, and many of these will be made and all need to fit exactly" then of course this answer would be different. The way the question is worded, this is the quickest method that gives a good result